# Logarithm Function in SPARQL Query

Tags: math, sparql, jena, logarithm

I am trying to create a `SPARQL` query that performs the logarithm function on the returned results.  I have implemented the Jena SPARQL engine in my java program, but have only been able to find these available functions : http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/library-function.html

Does anybody know of a way to take the logarithm (preferably the natural log) of a `SPARQL` return variable?

Example query that works:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ((?Transactions_Num) AS ?BusinessValue) 
WHERE {{?BusinessProcess relation:Transactions_Num ?Transactions_Num ;} }
```

Example of query that I want to work (though currently does not):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (LOG(?Transactions_Num) AS ?BusinessValue) 
WHERE {{?BusinessProcess relation:Transactions_Num ?Transactions_Num ;} }
```

Thanks you very much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log isn't part of the standard or [ARQ's additions](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-function.html), however it's [very easy to write your own](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/writing_functions.html).

```
package app;

public class log extends FunctionBase1
{
    public log() { super() ; }

    public NodeValue exec(NodeValue v)
    {
        return Math.log(v.getDouble());
    }
}
```

The easiest way to register it is like this:

```
FunctionRegistry.get().put("http://example.org/function#log", log.class) ;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
PREFIX myfun: <http://example.org/function#>
SELECT DISTINCT (myfun:log(?Transactions_Num) AS ?BusinessValue)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: A little clarification would be appreciated, though.  Does this class get added to the jena-core jar or to my java project?  I created it in my java project, but the class couldn't be cast as a FunctionFactory.  Should it be added to the jar?

Comment: Added a quick explanation of registering from your code. I believe it should work like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  That is really awesome not needing any manipulation of the jars themselves!  I am now trying to do the same with the Sesame API for use with OpenRDF's BigdataEngine.  The only site I can find with help is [rivuli](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/creating-custom-sparql-functions/) but I can't seem to get it to work.  I probably should open a new question but was wondering if you had any insight.